# Problem on if statements are "logically equivalent"

Tags: logic

I have got this problem:

---

Consider the following statements.

Statement A: If chimpanzees can write plays than Shakespeare was a chimpanzee.

Statement B: If Shakespeare was a chimpanzee then chimpanzees can write plays.

Statement C: If Shakespeare was not a chimpanzee then chimpanzees cannot write plays.

(a)Statements A and B are logically equivalent

(b)Statements A and C are logically equivalent

(c)Statements B and C are logically equivalent

(d)Statement B is the inverse of statement A

(e)Statement C is the inverse of statement A

---

Can anyone please kindly help me with this problem? Many thanks! I have tried to look it up on Wikipedia but I don't understand what it's saying. That's why I come here to ask for help.

If there's any source where I can learn more of this kind of problem please kindly leave them below.

Comment: Did you even attempt the problem? Any thoughts on it whatsoever?

Comment: You should research conditional statements, and the converse/inverse/contrapositive of conditional statements.

Comment: "If there's any source where I can learn more of this kind of problem". Yep. It's called a library. Look for books with titles like "Elementary Logic", "An Introduction to Logic", etc. etc.

Comment: I definitely tried but I don't even understand what "logically equivalent" means. I looked it up on Wikipedia but I don't understand what it's saying. That's why I come here to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is equivalent to $C$.
There is a law that states $a\Rightarrow b$ is same as not $a$ or  $b$.
If $a$ is "chimpanzees can write plays" 
and $b$ is "Shakespeare was a chimpanzee"
then the statements are
$A$: not $a$ or $b$
$B$: not $b$ or $a$
$C$: $b$ or not $a$
So alternative $b$ is correct.

Comment: Sorry I made a confusion here. (+1)